How to pass a variable like an ID to a URL in Playwright?
I'm creating a new user on a test in Playwright and at next point, I will need to take the id of this new user to to be deleted.
At the end of the code, I'm creating a variable with the id of this user, like this:
const loginResponseJson = await response.json();
const id = loginResponseJson.id;
console.log(id);
console.log("New Created User is: " + id);

And then my question is:
How to pass a variable like an ID to a URL in Playwright?
To delete, I should do like this:
test('Should be able to delete a new created user', async ({ request }) => {
const response = await request.delete(`/public/v2/users/`, {
});

The ID should enter after the URL in request, but I don't get to put this properly. How I pass this in Playwright?

Should be able to delete a new created user should work in isolation. That test should create the user and then try to delete it.

What I'm trying to do here is create the new user (this part is working ok) and the get the id from the response body to use on the next test, by sending a request to delete this new user.

Taking a step back, Playwright is probably the wrong library for this. It's a UI testing library, so generally you click buttons on the page to test things end to end. If you're doing requests, maybe just test services on the backend, or use supertest. There are rare cases where PW requests are useful for setting up state, but I'd avoid them. That said, if you want help with this, please share a [mcve]. It's not clear what block that top code bit is in exactly. I second hardkoded though, generally just put it all in one test or use a beforeEach hook. Tests should be idempotent, else pain.

You may use the Template literals feature in Javascript.
Template Literals: Use backticks (``) to create a template literal, which allows you to embed expressions inside${}` placeholders rather than the quotes ("") to define a string.
 test('Should be able to delete a new created user', async ({ request }) => {
       const response = await request.delete(`/public/v2/users/${id}`, {
 }); 

Resources:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_string_templates.asp
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/template-literals-in-javascript/
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

You could also concatenate the id to the URL string:
const id = someId; 
const response = await request.delete('/public/v2/users/' + id);


Thanks for the answer, but doesn't it seem like OP clearly understands string concatenation since they used it in their question? console.log("New Created User is: " + id);. I think the problem is less obvious--they're doing the top request code in a different block than the bottom block in their code, but exactly what they're asking is unclear because they didn't show a complete example.
